# Relacionar 4 tabelas do banco e realizar contas

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

Olá tenho 4 tabelas: Funcionarios, Empresas, Vencimentos e Descontos. Gostaria de apresentar uma espécie de Holerite. Minha ideia inicial foi trazer as todas as informações juntas e tratar na view da seguinte forma:

(OBS: estou usando blade do laravel)

```
@foreach ($funcionarios as $funcionario)
  @php
    $total_vencimentos = 0;
    $total_descontos = 0;
    $total_liquido = 0;
  @endphp
  @foreach ($vencimentos as $vencimento)
    @if ($funcionario->id == $vencimento->funcionario_id)
      imprime os vencimentos
    @endif
    @php $total_vencimentos += $vencimento->valor_adicionado @endphp
  @endforeach
  @foreach ($descontos as $desconto)
    @if ($funcionario->id == $desconto->funcionario_id)
      imprime os vencimentos
    @endif
    @php $total_vencimentos += $desconto->valor_descontado @endphp
  @endforeach
  @php
    $total_liquido = ($total_vencimentos - $total_descontos);
  @endphp
@endforeach
```

Desta view esta sendo gerado um PDF. Este código esta funcionando bem, mas me preocupo se esse processo pode ficar pesado com o aumento de funcionários na empresa, existe uma melhor solução ?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a alguns pontos, com o aumento do numero de funcionários claro que pode ficar mais lento, mas acredito que deveria se preocupar menos com o volume de dados e mais com a forma de buscar e tratar eles. Por exemplo, existem formas de montar consultas que retornam Gigas de dados em segundos, mas o que influencia muito no desempenho também, é a forma de tratar os dados após a consulta no banco.
Vou falar um pouco sobre boas práticas para MVC que vão melhorar o desempenho, nada muito técnico em questão de desenvolvimento...

Você citou: *trazer as todas as informações juntas e tratar na view*.

Veja o problema de fazer isso... Você está usando um framework MVC (Model - View - Controller), um dos maiores pecados que se pode cometer é "tratar" os dados no arquivo de visualização (View), pois pra isso servem os Controllers, você vai deixar os dados prontos e só enviar pra View, mesmo que em ultimo caso, tente minimizar os laços de foreachs enviando objetos mais completos pra View ao invés de percorrer vários arrays de objetos dentro dela. Você consegue resolver isso com alguns Joins na consulta no Controller.
Depois disso você pode testar várias formas de consultas e tratamentos no Controller, até mesmo usando os Models para otimizar as buscas (Laravel facilita muito nisso). Usar as boas práticas básicas de um frame MVC já vai te dar uma melhora significativa no desempenho e no fim vai notar que a menor preocupação será o volume de dados do banco.

Essa é uma resposta simples que pode ser complementada, sugestões adicionais são bem vindas.

Comment: Obrigado pelas recomendações, vou trazer a logica para o controller. Mas em questão do funcionamento ainda fiquei meio confuso. Afinal se eu realizar a consulta usando join, apenas uma linha de cada funcionário iria retornar e o que eu preciso é o funcionário -> empresa -> TODOS os vencimentos e TODOS os descontos. Por esse motivo chamava separado. É possível fazer essa consulta em uma unica query ?

Comment: Se voce tiver uma chave em comum nas tabelas é possivel sim, nesse caso acredito que tenha um campo com id da empresa ou do funcionario em todas as tabelas entao ficaria bem mais facil, se precisar de ajuda na montagem da query acho que caberia até abrir outro tópico para ajudarmos.

Comment: Eu tenho a chave, e sim a duvida era realmente em como montar. Vou abrir uma nova question. Obrigado...